# Displaying Guest Policies Applied to a Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine Instance Using the REST API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, rest

I am able to display the OSConfig guest policies that are applied to a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Compute Engine (GCE) instance (`$GCE_INSTANCE_NAME`) using the Cloud SDK (`gcloud`):

```sh
gcloud beta compute os-config guest-policies lookup \
$GCE_INSTANCE_NAME \
--zone=$GCE_INSTANCE_ZONE

#=>

┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                           SOFTWARE RECIPES                                               │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────┬─────────┬───────────────┤
│                          SOURCE                           │        NAME        │ VERSION │ DESIRED_STATE │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────┼─────────┼───────────────┤
│ projects/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/guestPolicies/. . .              │        . . .       │ . . .   │   . . .       │
│ projects/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/guestPolicies/$GUEST_POLICY_NAME │ $GUEST_POLICY_NAME │ 1.0     │ INSTALLED     │
│ projects/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/guestPolicies/. . .              │        . . .       │ . . .   │   . . .       │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────┴─────────┴───────────────┘
```

How would I retrieve the same response using the REST API?  The `lookup` method seems to be missing from the `projects.guestPolicies` resource page [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/osconfig/rest/v1beta/projects.guestPolicies#methods).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the `projects.zones.instances.lookupEffectiveGuestPolicy` REST method, found [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/osconfig/rest/v1beta/projects.zones.instances/lookupEffectiveGuestPolicy).

An example for a guest policy that installs software on **any** version of Ubuntu:

```sh
curl \
--data-raw '{ "osArchitecture": "", "osShortName": "UBUNTU", "osVersion": "" }' \
--header "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--location \
--request POST \
"https://osconfig.googleapis.com/v1beta/projects/$GCP_PROJECT_NUMBER/zones/$GCE_INSTANCE_ZONE/instances/$GCE_INSTANCE_NAME:lookupEffectiveGuestPolicy"

#=>

{
  "softwareRecipes": [
    . . .
    {
      "source": "projects/$GCP_PROJECT_NUMBER/guestPolicies/$GUEST_POLICY_NAME",
      "softwareRecipe": {
        "name": "$GUEST_POLICY_NAME",
        "version": "1.0",
        . . .
        "desiredState": "INSTALLED"
      }
    },
    . . .
  ]
}
```

**Note**: `$GCP_PROJECT_NUMBER` is **different** than `$GCP_PROJECT_ID`:

```sh
gcloud projects describe $GCP_PROJECT_NAME

#=>

. . .
projectId: $GCP_PROJECT_ID
projectNumber: "$GCP_PROJECT_NUMBER"
```

**Note**: The values for the POST body keys

- `"osArchitecture"`
- `"osShortName"`
- `"osVersion"`

can be found for `$GUEST_POLICY_NAME` using either `gcloud`:

```sh
gcloud beta compute os-config guest-policies describe \
$GUEST_POLICY_NAME \
--flatten="assignment.osTypes" \
--format="table[box](assignment.osTypes.osArchitecture,
                     assignment.osTypes.osShortName,
                     assignment.osTypes.osVersion)"

#=>

┌─────────────────┬───────────────┬────────────┐
│ OS_ARCHITECTURE │ OS_SHORT_NAME │ OS_VERSION │
├─────────────────┼───────────────┼────────────┤
│ . . .           │ . . .         │ . . .      │
│                 │ UBUNTU        │            │
│ . . .           │ . . .         │ . . .      │
└─────────────────┴───────────────┴────────────┘
```

or the REST API:

```sh
curl \
--header "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
--location \
--request GET \
"https://osconfig.googleapis.com/v1beta/projects/$GCP_PROJECT_NUMBER/guestPolicies/$GUEST_POLICY_NAME"

#=>

{
    . . .
    "assignment": {
        . . .
        "osTypes": [
            . . .
            {
                "osShortName": "UBUNTU"
            }
            . . .
        ]
        . . .
    },
    . . .
}
```

**Note**: if `"osArchitecture"` and/or `"osVersion"` are missing or blank, you should leave these values as empty strings when using the REST method above (`""`).